# multiple Lua VMs detected in Xcode

Tags: xcode, lua

I build lua as a dynamic library target and another dynamic library target depend on it.
When i require my lib,here's a error: multiple Lua VMs detected.
I found a solution under gcc by adding -Wl,-E link flag [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14213559/lua5-2s-error-multiple-lua-vms-detected). But how to do in Xcode?

Update: I try to use -weak_library to link lua in my target also catch "multiple Lua VMs detected" error.

Comment: I've never included Lua in my own projects, but I'd bet your solution would be to change the library to be weak-linked to the app.

Answer (score 1):

You should not link the second dynamic library with Lua. Leave it as a dependency. I'm not sure how to express this in Xcode. Also, as far as I know, there is no need to use `-Wl,-E` in Mac OS X.